# Migrate a TFVC repository from one project to another?

Tags: azure-devops, migration, tfvc

I have a TFVC repository to migrate but I only find a way to migrate it to a git or backwards.

Answer (score 0):

TFVC does not support migration between team projects. You may consider to migrate to a temporary git and then to a new TFVC repository ([Migrate Git repository to new TFVC repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349494/migrate-git-repository-to-new-tfvc-repository)), but that may be too complex way.

Answer (score -1):

```
Step 1 : Download git-tfs using cmd, use the below given command to download.
curl -L -o  GitTfs-0.30.0.zip "https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases/download/v0.30/GitTfs-0.30.0.zip"

Step 2 : unzip GitTfs-0.30.0.zip and check "git-tfs.exe -version" in the cmd prompt.

Step 3 : Cloning tfvc repository from azure.
        git-tfs.exe clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/some_project
          (wait for git-tfs to pull your history) (-or-)
        git-tfs.exe quick-clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/some_project
          (cd some_project and hack away, using only git, until you need to share with TFS…)

Step 4 :  Pushing git repository 
git remote add new git@newserver:newproject.git
note - git@newserver:newproject.git is Bitbucket repo

Step 5 : git push --mirror new
```