# How to migrate TFVC to TFVC (not to Git) between organizations?

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I'm working on a AzDO migration.
Some of my projects have TFVC repos, I need to lift and shift them to different organization.

I don't have visual studio subscription, instead have VS code (However, it should not be the requirement).

How do I migrate TFVC to TFVC (not Git) including history?

They are definitely bigger than 1 GB of size and have multiple branches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a workaround is in order:

1. Create a git repository from the original TFVC organization (this will preserve history).
2. Import the new git repo to the second organization (will serve are history reference).
3. Convert new git repository to TFVC in second organization.

References:

[Migrate from TFVC to git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/devops/develop/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git)

[Convert Git repository to TFVC version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397169/convert-git-repository-to-tfvc-version-control)

[Migrate Git repository to new TFVC repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349494/migrate-git-repository-to-new-tfvc-repository)