# Migrate repo in azure devops under TFVC to new organization with different AD under TFVC

Tags: azure-devops

I have a repo under TFVC format in azure devops, I want to migrate the repo to new organization under different Active Directory. May I know how I can migrate or clone it to new organization. There is no clone as what GIT does has. I want remain the repo as TFVC format but not Git

Comment: Hi buble bub, what's the latest status of your issue? Has my post helped?

Comment: Hi @CeenoQi-MSFT.  I'm not able to convert it back to TFVC from Git.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a usual workaround for this is to migrate `TFVC to GIT to TFVC`.

It is suggested that you could [import your TFVC repo into git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops), and then in your local git folder,  and use `git-tf checkin --deep` command to [checkin the local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349494/migrate-git-repository-to-new-tfvc-repository) to a TFVC team project.

===============================================================

**update 12/7**

I suppose that you need to install the `git-tf` [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474)first, and then you could refer to this [git-tf command guidance](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiBo5ri4eb7AhXmlNgFHYDqDrUQFnoECB4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FA%2FE%2F2%2FAE23B059-5727-445B-91CC-15B7A078A7F4%2FGit-TF_GettingStarted.html&usg=AOvVaw1Xk-Tfr0JvIbOuzERkgQC-).

> **Configure**
>
> `git tf configure http://myserver:8080/tfs/collectionName $/TeamProjectA/Main [--deep]`
>
> Configures an existing git repo to be able to communicate with a TFS
> server. Like the clone command, the --deep option may be used to set
> the default for future fetch and checkin operations.
>
> **Checkin**
>
> `git tf checkin [--deep]`
>
> Checks in the changes made in the Git repo into TFS. By default, the
> checkin command will create a single TFS changeset for the aggregate
> of all changes made on the current branch in Git since the last
> checkin to TFS. When used with the --deep option, a TFS changeset will
> be created for each Git commit on the current branch since the last
> checkin to TFS.

Comment: May I know what the means of local git folder?  After I import my TFVC repo into git repo, I need download it into my local computer using Visual Studio and then check in to the git repo into my new organization under TFVC type?

Comment: @BubbleBub Hi bub, we suppose so.

Comment: Any reference how I can push my clone git repo into new TFVC repo?

Comment: @BubbleBub this ticket for [migrate git to tfvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349494/migrate-git-repository-to-new-tfvc-repository) could help you with the migration

Comment: @BubbleBub , hi I have updated my answer. You need to use the `git-tf` tool for the migration.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Beside git-tf, is there any other way to convert it or another other ways I no need install any tools or modify the system.  Sorry to ask so because a lot of restriction in the installation and modify the Path environment.

Comment: Hi I suppose not. `Git-tf` is essential